# Order an non-standard keyboard layout on new MacBook

Tags: keyboard, macbook-pro, internationalization

Is it possible to order a new MacBook with a keyboard that's non-standard for a given country? Let's say I want to have a Norwegian keyboard, but I'm living in Australia. Is this possible? And if it is, how to do it?

I've asked in one Apple shop, but I really hope their answer isn't the final one.

Comment: Perhaps if you order in the Norwegian shop?

Comment: I have a feeling you'll have problems with VAT/GST if you order from one country's shop and send it to a different country.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the only way to do this is to contact an Apple retail store directly yourself and ask if they can do a special order for you.  No guarantees, but I have heard that it works for things like Arabic in the US.

http://www.apple.com/retail/

Comment: Sounds like this might be something to try, find a shop and ask there. http://www.apple.com/au/retail/